# Sale Items not showing original price

Tags: product

New to magento.

Hi, So we are having a problem where some of the sales items are not showing their original pricing on the product page.

How other sale items look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tWsc.jpg

How this item looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFxyq.jpg

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Admin panel edit product go to Price tab, provide normal price let's say 1,119 and provide special price let's say 999. Clear cache and it should show both prices as per https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tWsc.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Cache has been cleared multiple time since this problem, it started about a month ago.